# How to create rewrite rule that allows to rewrite something right after slash with exceptions

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

i want to create these rewrite rules:

From:

```
www.something.com/name-of-some-product
```

To:

```
www.something.com/index.php?site=name-of-some-product
```

But I also need to use images and some other files and also other PHP files.

The .htaccess i have:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !(\.png|\.jpg|\.gif|\.jpeg|\.bmp|\.css)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?site=$1 [QSA]
```

The problem is when i try to load file like this:

```
www.something.com/another_php_file.php?parameter=value
```

It doesn't work, because i don't know how to avoid rewriting PHP files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this Rule,

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?site=$1 [QSA]
```

Comment: That's exactly what i was looking for! Thank you :)